# How can I determinine all functions or a function f?

Tags: problem-solving, functional-equations

Determine all functions $f$ in $f(x+1)=2f(x)$, for all $x$ in real number.

So I let $x$ be $x+1$. Then I have $f((x+1)+1)=2f(x+1)$. But since there is a new function $f(x+2)$, I couldn't determine the function $f$ using elimination. Any idea would be a great help.

Comment: Put $f(0) = a$. Can you find values for f(1), f(2) etc. Do you see a pattern? How about f(-1), f(-2)... Make a conjecture about f(x) when x is an integer.

Comment: Hint: $f(n) = 2f(n-1) = 4f(n-2) = \ldots = 2^k f(n-k)$.

Comment: Yes, I see that there's a pattern with the function, but the thing is, how can I able to graph it on a coordinate plane?

Answer (score 5):

There are very many such functions if those constraints you have given are the only constraints.

For example, you can define an *arbitrary* function $F:[0,1)\to \mathbb R$. Then you can "extend" it to the whole real axis: on $[1,2)$ make it *twice* $F$, on $[2,3)$ make it $4$ times $F$, on $[-1,0)$ make it *half* $F$ etc. The way to write it in one formula:

$$f(x)=2^{\lfloor x\rfloor}F(x-\lfloor x\rfloor)$$

where $\lfloor x\rfloor$ denotes "the biggest integer not bigger than $x$".

One can prove that $f(x)=F(x)$ for $x\in[0,1)$, and any such function $f$ must be obtained this way, by extending its own restriction on $[0,1)$ - thus the above construction produces all such functions $f$.

Comment: Yes. Let say I have a restriction: for x ∈ (0, 1], f(x) = x(x − 1).

Comment: Well, it will be $f(x)=2^{\lfloor x\rfloor}(x-\lfloor x\rfloor)(x-\lfloor x\rfloor-1)$, if you are looking for a formula.

Answer (score 1):

Define $\,g(x) := f(x)2^{-x}.\,$ Then $\,g(x+1) = g(x)\,$ for all real $x$. Thus, $\,g(x)\,$ is a period $1$ real function. Conversely, **any**
period 1 real function $\,g(x)\,$ determines uniquely the correspoinding $\,f(x)\,$ satisfying $\,f(x+1) = 2f(x).$

Comment: How did you come up with that definition?

Comment: @BillyClaxtone An obvious solution to the original equation is $2^x$, and if we divide $f(x)$ by that we get a solution to $g(x+1)=g(x)$ as  I wrote in my answer.